# What do you call it when you refuse to give up on a particular task

Tags: word-choice, expressions, translation

In Dutch we've got the expression 'Vastbijten in'. It means you really get into a problem or some work. And you won't give up till it's resolved. I've been looking all over the web, but I've not been able to find an expression that comes close enough.

Is there a way of saying this en English? The Dutch expression is a verb phrase, so that would probably come closest.

### Edit

Thank you all very much for your answers:). Since I can only accept one final answer, I feel the need to do some clarification. Initially I added the single word request, since the expression in Dutch is just one word (not including the preposition). However, that's very specific to the Dutch language and I'm mostly looking for an expression that comes closest. Therefore I feel that:

- `to get one's teeth into` Comes closest, it's actually almost an exact translation both literally and in meaning.
- `indefatigable` Is the best candidate when a single word is required(although the literal translation in dutch for this would be 'onvermoeibaar'). This also is an interesting choice since vastbijten can be used as noun(`vastbijter`), meaning an indefatigable person.
- `to dig in` Would be probably the American equivalent of to get one's teeth into. Also not one word, but approaching the meaning closest.

Comment: The English idiom is close to sense of the Dutch. We'd say "I've got my teeth in it."

Comment: Two terms that may or may not apply:  "Diehard", and "stupid".

Comment: *Tenacious, perseverant, pertinacious, determined.*

Comment: *Dig in* (verb) and *tenacious* (adjective) are the terms I would use for this in both the US and Australia.

Comment: "Dogged" has animal nuances

Comment: Since I'm quite new here I don't really know what the protocol is. I've taken the translation as a reference point. This my not do justice to my inquiry however. So please let me know if I should change anything:).

Comment: Please [edit] this to explain whether you want a noun, verb or adjective.

Comment: @curiousdannii Thank you for noticing that lapse in my question. I wasn't actually looking for a single word, but an expression. I've changed my question (rather my tags) accordingly.

Comment: @laurisvr Even so, you should specify whether you want a verb phrase, a noun phrase, an adjectival phrase, or an adverbial phrase.

Comment: @curiousdannii I'd prefer a verb phrase. I'll update my question in a bit. Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An almost-literal translation is *to get one's teeth into* something.

> Work energetically and productively on (a task):
>   *the course gives students something to get their teeth into*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/get-or-sink-one%27s-teeth-into)

A slightly more prosaic alternative might be *persevere;* that connotes slightly less enthusiasm for the task at hand.

Comment: American here. We use "sink one's teeth into"

Answer (score 7):

"persistent", "dogged", "indefatigable".

Comment: At ELU this response resembles a comment more than an answer as it lacks definitions, examples of usage, citation to authoritative sources and no links to same. Your answers will be much more favorably received (which will be reflected in upvotes) if they contain these qualities. Just trying to be helpful.  :-)

Comment: @LittleEva: Maybe so, but it is still the best answer given here so far, IMO. It's not difficult for someone to check the meanings of those 3 words. I do agree, of course, that the answer would be better with some additional explanation or definition. But as an answer to "What do you call it...?" this is OK, IMO (minimal, but OK).

Comment: @Drew - the offered words are appropriate, indeed. However, a "good" answer involves more than what is included here. My suggested improvements are not attempts to foist my personal opinion on anyone, but are actual ELU protocol - just look around and you will notice the examples of long-term users (usually, though not always, they are discernible by their rep points) which almost always contain what I have spoken of above.

Comment: I'm with LittleEva here: although this is not "Not An Answer", this is not a good answer. It's the sort of answer which is normally converted to a comment. I won't do that as I'm not exactly disinterested but if I hadn't had an answer here myself I would have done. Other moderators may yet do that, votes or no.

Comment: @Bob, thank you very much for your answer. I think yours comes closest to my description above. However as a translation goes `get one's teeth into` comes a bit closer. Please see the clarification in my post on top:).

Comment: The title is the definition of *persistent*.

Comment: @laurisvr, I've re-read the question based on your comment, and you are right.  I took "a problem" to be generic; I thought the OP was looking for a quality in a person, the kind of person who, when given a problem, will not give up until it's resolved.  I realize now that "a problem" means the specific problem at hand, and the OP is looking for a word describing the present situation, not the qualities of a person.

Comment: @Bob Op reporting;) But you're right the title was a bit of. Describing words isn't my strong suit I'm afraid. Hope it's clearer now:).

Comment: @AndrewLeach, LittleEva: thanks for your constructive mentoring.   I am new to this, wasn't aware of the conventions you have now taught me.  I have to say that I often find minimalist (but responsive) answers quite valuable, and in those cases examples and definitions, are to me, sometimes of little added value.   But I understand the motivation for the norms and will try to do better next time!

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a single word, as your tag suggests, may I recommend:

**[indefatigable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/indefatigable)**

> never giving up or getting tired of doing something
>
> *an indefatigable defender of human rights*
>
> *She was indefatigable in her search for the truth*.

[From oxford]

Comment: Please note that the [actual source of quotes must appear in plain text](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/new-attribution-rules/5196#5196), not just as a link.

Comment: @Bob, thank you very much for your answer. I think yours comes closest to my description above. However as a translation goes get one's teeth into comes a bit closer. Please see the clarification in my post on top:).

Answer (score 2):

***[Tooth and nail](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tooth%20and%20nail)***:

> - with all one's resources or energy; fiercely:
>
>   - *We fought tooth and nail till the end.*
>   - *The market has changed, but the major players are fighting tooth and nail to keep going the way things have been.*

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: We worked tooth and nail?

Comment: OP seems to refer to a problem to solve at work. They  idea is that they are going to fight tooth and nail to solve it.

Comment: J Lawler's suggestion is a far better fit. There is not a single 'tooth and nail' not prefaced by a form of 'fight' in the examples at Dictionary.com. The implication is of sentient opposition; OP mentions a problem / task.

Comment: I didn't say Prof. Lawler suggestion is not good.

Answer (score 1):

In American English a few common sayings are:

["dig in"](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/dig-in) - which would fit closely with the dutch expression

["come hell or high water"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/come-hell-or-high-water) - meaning that no obstacle will stop your efforts

["In for the long haul"](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/in-it-for-the-long-haul) - expressing a commitment to finish what is started

Single word options:

[relentless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relentless) - literally "does not stop"

[indefatigable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indefatigable) - literally "does not tire" (this is a bit archaic to American ears)

Comment: Please cite to authority and include links to references.

Comment: That's great. I don't mean to plague you, H.R., but you should (according to site protocols) also include citations to referenced authorities (in addition to each link) in plain text (due to link-rot), with quoted passaged appearing in red-block. Take a look at Area 51 Detective Fiction (w/comments) & our Moderator, Andrew Leach's offerings, as good examples of what the site requests in an answer. BTW, all else being equal, including these features will substantially increase the likelihood that your answers/questions will be upvoted.  :-)

Comment: @H.R.Rambler Thank you for your answer. I think `dig in` would indeed be the american English equivalent for `vastbijten`. Please see the edit of my question for further clarification:).

Answer (score 0):

Dedicate is close to that. If you dedicate yourself to a task, it means you will work until it is complete.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dedicate

> To devote wholly and earnestly, as to some person or purpose:
>   He dedicated his life to fighting corruption.

Answer (score 0):

The verbs **grapple** and **wrestle** are commonly used in this sort of situation; this is metaphorical extension. The 'refusal to let go' implication is clear.

> **grapple**  v.intr.
>
> 3. a. To wrestle with an opponent by clutching or gripping.
>
> b. To struggle or work hard to deal with something: grappled with
>   their consciences; grapple with the political realities of our time.
>
> [[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth
>   Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing
>   Company](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grapple)]

Answer (score 0):

[Eat, Sleep and Breathe (Something)](http://www.eslnewscast.com/2012/08/04/phrase-of-the-day-eat-sleep-and-breathe-something/)

> “He **eats, sleeps and breathes** poker, playing it for over nine
>   hours each day.”
>
> Definition: If you **eat, sleep and breathe** something, then that means
>   you are obsessed with it and spend most of your time doing it.