# The opposite of capitulating compromiser

Tags: word-choice

I was watching the movie Lincoln last night in which Thadeus Stevens, an abolitionist refers to Lincoln as a 'capitulating compromiser'.

And that got me thinking about a term that could be used to describe Stevens  who was a much strong defender of equality when compared to Lincoln. How do you refer to someone who adamantly refuses to compromise? I came up with 'adamant defender' but it doesn't have the same effect as the original. What do you think would be a better alternative?

Comment: It kind of depends whether you mean in a negative way, as in stubborn, or open-minded but just strongly sticking to your principles. Because I think of a lot of words for stubborn or adamant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you call it when you refuse to give up on a particular task](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244537/what-do-you-call-it-when-you-refuse-to-give-up-on-a-particular-task)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**obstinate**. [enter link description here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/obstinate)

> a. Stubbornly adhering to an attitude, opinion, or course of action;
>   obdurate. b. Characterized by such adherence: an obstinate refusal.

As in:

> He was an obstinate negotiator, unyielding in his thinking!

Comment: That gets my vote.

Answer (score 1):

intransigent, both verb and noun

adj
not willing to compromise; obstinately maintaining an attitude
n
(Government, Politics & Diplomacy) an intransigent person, esp in politics
[Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/intransigent)

Comment: That's perfect actually.

Comment: @Abhishek Mhatre You'll want to be careful though, this word, like all others words used so far carry a connotation of stubborness, it's not may or may not be positive. More general terms are principled and incorruptible.

Answer (score 0):

How about an "uncompromising holdout".  Couldn't think of one with nice alliteration, though.

Comment: I know, it is really difficult to find a positive term. I came up with "unyielding fundamentalist" but the contemporary religious connation gives it a bad vibe.

Comment: I meant having the same letter or sound at the beginning of the words (as "capitulating compromiser") does.  I did not see the movie, so I do not know the context.  Consider that  one who capitulates and compromises could be one who will give up on their own morals and ideology simply to reach a settlement.  I'm not sure if that is such a wonderful thing.  Likewise, something antithetical to the "capitulating compromiser" may not be all that positive either---someone who cannot compromise at all.

Comment: People generally preceive principled and unwavering public figure in a positive maneer and pragmatic ones in a negative maneer. That is why JFK is so much more popular than LBJ. I find it slightly puzzling that we cannot find a positive term for the former though plenty of harsh and negative ones for the latter.

Comment: That may be true, but I think that JFK is more popular than LBJ for many reasons:  JFK started the civil rights "ball" in motion;  JFK was better looking and affable; LBJ was largely responsible for the entrenching the US in Vietnam (marking him forever as a villain regardless of his other accomplishments); and JFK was martyred.  Also, historical views can and will change as future people look at history through lenses colored by their cultures and experiences.

Comment: I think you are right about JFK v LBJ. A better example would be Bernie Sanders and Hillary Clinton. Sen. Sanders is clearly a populist with a relatively unchanging set of beliefs and values while Sec. Clinton is a much more more prudential and ideologically flexible. People generally like the former more than the latter but also find him and his initiatives impractical.